# ASP .NET Core: Routing. несколько категорий в начале URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Итак, есть задача:

Надо пропускать запросы на урл

```
site.com/events/2017/06/wwdc.html
```

или же в более общем виде

```
site.com/category1/subcategory1/subcategory2/...../subcategoryN/page-title.html
```

как ещё один пример:

```
site.com/cars/tesla/model-s/is-it-worth-it.html
```

на контроллер `ArticlesController` c action `Index(string title)` или какой-то такой...

Во время компиляции кол-во этих подкатегорий не известно, то есть один article может иметь 1 категорию и всё, а другой штуки 3-4, а то и 5. Но однозначно известно то, что все такие страницы заканчиваются на `/pageTitle.html`, где pageTitle -- это некоторый заголовок страницы, вероятно, уникальный.

Встроенными средствами роутинга ASP.Net Core я не нашел пути это реализовать, а документация не слишком то поясняет, как можно переопределить поведение.

Так вот, возможно ли так сделать и если да, то как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если поставить это в конец файла что-то такое, то всё должно заработать, но придётся вручную всё разбирать.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "category-article",
            template: "{*article}",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "Home",
                action = "ReadCategoryAndPage"
            });
    });
```

[Более подробный ответ тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42331841/asp-net-core-routing-multiple-categories-in-url-at-begining)